# symfony 4 - Semantical Error with relation ManyToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have started a project with Symfony and I'm a beginner with this framework. I'm usually able to correct all my errors by reading forums and documentation but in this case, I can not understand the error.

I have a `WorkingTime` entity with many `ManyToMany` relation :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\WorkingTimeRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=WorkingTimeRepository::class)
 */
class WorkingTime
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="workingTimes")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Customer::class, inversedBy="workingTimes")
     */
    private $customer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Work::class, inversedBy="workingTimes")
     */
    private $work;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=WorkingPlaceRelation::class, inversedBy="workingTimes")
     */
    private $workingPlace;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $totalTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $kmPerso;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $meal;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->customer = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->work = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->workingPlace = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \datetime);
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|User[]
     */
    public function getUser(): Collection
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user): self
    {
        if (!$this->user->contains($user)) {
            $this->user[] = $user;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user): self
    {
        if ($this->user->contains($user)) {
            $this->user->removeElement($user);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Customer[]
     */
    public function getCustomer(): Collection
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    public function addCustomer(Customer $customer): self
    {
        if (!$this->customer->contains($customer)) {
            $this->customer[] = $customer;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCustomer(Customer $customer): self
    {
        if ($this->customer->contains($customer)) {
            $this->customer->removeElement($customer);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Work[]
     */
    public function getWork(): Collection
    {
        return $this->work;
    }

    public function addWork(Work $work): self
    {
        if (!$this->work->contains($work)) {
            $this->work[] = $work;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeWork(Work $work): self
    {
        if ($this->work->contains($work)) {
            $this->work->removeElement($work);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|WorkingPlaceRelation[]
     */
    public function getWorkingPlace(): Collection
    {
        return $this->workingPlace;
    }

    public function addWorkingPlace(WorkingPlaceRelation $workingPlace): self
    {
        if (!$this->workingPlace->contains($workingPlace)) {
            $this->workingPlace[] = $workingPlace;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeWorkingPlace(WorkingPlaceRelation $workingPlace): self
    {
        if ($this->workingPlace->contains($workingPlace)) {
            $this->workingPlace->removeElement($workingPlace);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalTime(): ?int
    {
        return $this->totalTime;
    }

    public function setTotalTime(?int $totalTime): self
    {
        $this->totalTime = $totalTime;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getKmPerso(): ?int
    {
        return $this->kmPerso;
    }

    public function setKmPerso(?int $kmPerso): self
    {
        $this->kmPerso = $kmPerso;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMeal(): ?int
    {
        return $this->meal;
    }

    public function setMeal(?int $meal): self
    {
        $this->meal = $meal;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I would like to create a custom query in the repository of this entity:

```php
public function findByDate($date)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('w')
        ->where('w.createdAt = :date')
        ->setParameter('date', $date)
        ->orderBy('w.customer.firstname', 'ASC')
        ->setMaxResults(10)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

But I get the following error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 85 near 'name ASC': Error: Class
> App\Entity\WorkingTime has no field or association named
> customer.firstname

you can see my customer Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Work;
use App\Repository\CustomerRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Unique;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CustomerRepository::class)
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Regex(
     * pattern = "/^[0-9]{5}$/",
     * message = "Le numéro de client ne peut être qu'un chiffre")
     */
    private $customer_number;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $compagny_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\Regex(
     * pattern = "/^[0-9]{4}$/",
     * message = "Le code postal doit contenir 4 chiffres")
     */
    private $zip_code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     */
    private $active;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Work::class, mappedBy="customer", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $works;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=WorkingTime::class, mappedBy="customer")
     */
    private $workingTimes;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->works = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->setActive(1);
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $this->workingTimes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCustomerNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->customer_number;
    }

    public function setCustomerNumber(?string $customer_number): self
    {
        $this->customer_number = $customer_number;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCompagnyName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->compagny_name;
    }

    public function setCompagnyName(?string $compagny_name): self
    {
        $this->compagny_name = $compagny_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(?string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function setLastname(?string $lastname): self
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStreet(): ?string
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    public function setStreet(?string $street): self
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getZipCode(): ?int
    {
        return $this->zip_code;
    }

    public function setZipCode(?int $zip_code): self
    {
        $this->zip_code = $zip_code;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(?string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(?string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(?string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $created_at): self
    {
        $this->created_at = $created_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updated_at): self
    {
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getActive(): ?int
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    public function setActive(int $active): self
    {
        $this->active = $active;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Work[]
     */
    public function getWorks(): Collection
    {
        return $this->works;
    }

    public function addWork(Work $work): self
    {
        if (!$this->works->contains($work)) {
            $this->works[] = $work;
            $work->setCustomer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeWork(Work $work): self
    {
        if ($this->works->contains($work)) {
            $this->works->removeElement($work);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($work->getCustomer() === $this) {
                $work->setCustomer(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|WorkingTime[]
     */
    public function getWorkingTimes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->workingTimes;
    }

    public function addWorkingTime(WorkingTime $workingTime): self
    {
        if (!$this->workingTimes->contains($workingTime)) {
            $this->workingTimes[] = $workingTime;
            $workingTime->addCustomer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeWorkingTime(WorkingTime $workingTime): self
    {
        if ($this->workingTimes->contains($workingTime)) {
            $this->workingTimes->removeElement($workingTime);
            $workingTime->removeCustomer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: customer is an entity (or even multiple entities). you can't order by an entity. select a field of that entity or something

Comment: Thank's for your reply @Jakumi i have tested with ->orderBy('w.customer.firstname', 'ASC') but i have already an error

Comment: well it won't be the same error, please update your question (append), so that we can follow code changes and new errors that occur.

Comment: In the above code, a WorkingTime can have many Customers and a Customer can have many WorkingTimes. Your Doctrine query is going to return an array of WorkingTimes which were created on a specified date with a maximum of 10 results. What exactly are you trying to order these by? If each WorkingTime has many Customers then trying to order your WorkingTime array by customer name doesn't make much sense. Is it actually that you want the Customers of the WorkingTime ordered alphabetically by name, rather than the WorkingTime itself?

Comment: Not related to the question, but since the relation between WorkingTime and Customer is a ManyToMany, your property in WorkingTime should be at the plural form $customers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the customers like this:

```
public function findByDate($date)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('w')
        ->join('w.customer', 'u')
        ->where('w.createdAt = :date')
        ->setParameter('date', $date)
        ->orderBy('u.firstname', 'ASC')
        ->setMaxResults(10)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Rawburner